# Appending to array with variable but saving that append when variable changes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable that is passed to a `UIViewController`. It is a string type. When it loads in the `UIView`, it appends to an array. That array will then be used to create cells in a `UITableView`; however, I cannot find a way to save that appended part when I want to add another cell(going to the other view controller, adding text to a text field, adding that text to the variable, passing the variable to the view controller holding the table view.) However, when I go to add the second cell, it just replaces the first cell.

Code from table view controller:

```
Class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var habitTableView : UITableView

@IBAction func addItemTapped(x:  UIButton) {


}

var habits: String[] = []
var habit:String = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.habitTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    println("It passed: \(habit)")

    habits.append(habit)



}
```

Code from other view controller:

```
class HabitCreator : UIViewController {

var habit:String = ""

@IBOutlet var habitTextField: UITextField

@IBAction func habitEntered(x: UIButton) {

    habit = habitTextField.text

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if(segue.identifier == "habitSegue") {
        var hvc = segue!.destinationViewController as SecondViewController

        hvc.habit = habit
    }
}
```

Comment: You can manage habits in HabitCreator and pass not single habit, but all to the second viewcontroller

Comment: Because of your tableView's  array create each time, so old value will be remove each time (At whenerve you pop viewContrl for pass another value). in your case you need to add your value in strong reference, such like SQLlite database, CoreData, of use NSUserDefaults

Comment: @AlexButenko I'm hitting myself for not thinking of this earlier. Thank you very much! Worked like a charm.